# StringBuilder is not appending the location address

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working to get the address on click of the Maps in android. I am using Geocoder to get the current location passing the latitude and longitude. The geocoder gets the list of addresses. When I try to using the StringBuilder to split by , and return the address, I get a null result. This same code works in an emulator, but when I run the code in my LG Android device, I don't get any value for the Address. This is what I have tried so far.

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            Double lat = latLng.latitude;
            Double lng = latLng.longitude;
            String address = getAddressFromLatLng(latLng);
        }
    });

private String getAddressFromLatLng(LatLng latLng) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Inside getAddress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress=null;
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
        if(addresses != null){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Addresses is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Returned address " + returnedAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "str address " + strReturnedAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for(int i=0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(",");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strReturnedAddress.toString();
}
```

The Toast value from the Returned address actually returns a list of address. After that the next statement I do `strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder();`. The toast statement following the address returns null. And this happens only on a real device. The same code works great in an emulator. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `Geocoder`? That's returning null, so please add it

Comment: `"str address " + strReturnedAddress` will always be empty, it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
    strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "str address " + strReturnedAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for(int i=0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
        strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(",");
    }
```

To

```
        strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
            strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(",");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "str address " + strReturnedAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The reason you are getting 'null' is that your 'strReturnedAddress' is actually empty.

Also you might find it more helpful to store your Context in a private variable instead of calling it multiple times. Calling 'getContext()' slows down the main thread.